# How to get the object used to create a row in a RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

After trying everything I could, I ask for help. Here is my problem:

## Context

I am building an Android Application. Everything is fine, except for one part.
I have a RecyclerView in a fragment of the MainActivity. I've made an adapter and a ViewHolder to populate it, based on an object called "Entry", consisting of the following things : id, name, description, amount. I work with Room Database to store them. It works very well, I can populate my RecyclerView without any problem.

## Code

Adapter and ViewHolder :

```
public class EntryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EntryAdapter.ViewHolderEntry>
{
    private List<Entry> entries;

    EntryAdapter(List<Entry> entries)
    {
        this.entries = entries;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolderEntry onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View contactView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolderEntry(contactView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderEntry viewHolder, int position)
    {
        Entry entry = entries.get(position);

        viewHolder.nameTextView.setText(entry.getName());
        viewHolder.descriptionTextView.setText(entry.getDescription());
        viewHolder.dueTextView.setText(String.valueOf(entry.getDue()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return entries.size();
    }

    class ViewHolderEntry extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        private TextView nameTextView;
        private TextView descriptionTextView;
        private TextView dueTextView;

        ViewHolderEntry(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);

            this.nameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameView);
            this.descriptionTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionView);
            this.dueTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dueView);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the layout used for a row :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/customborder"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameView"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dueView"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:layout_gravity="center|end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonDotMenu"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/dotbutton" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descriptionView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.85"
            android:lines="4"
            android:textColor="@color/colorDetails"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonValidate"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/iconcheck" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And its look :

[list_row.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6ikZ.png)

## The problem

And now the part where I fail. My goal is simple : when the user clicks the green check, a popup appears with the information of the row and he can edit/delete it (using Room).
But the id of the entries are incremental, so the first row's id for the entry is not 1 but any int. How can I get this information ? Because I need it to update or delete the corresponding entry. Can I put a variable inside a row ? Or find the object associated with the row ?

Thank you !

Comment: Can you post your Entity **Entry** model class?

Comment: Use an interface to create a callback when the row is clicked either passing the id or the object itself from your list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need create an interface to handle the click event in your Adapter.

```
interface OnAdapterClick{
        void OnItemClicked(View v, int position);
    }
```

When you have the interface attached between Activity and Adapter

```
 private List<Entry> entries;
    private OnAdapterClick clickListener;

    EntryAdapter(List<Entry> entries, OnAdapterClick  clickListener)
    {
        this.entries = entries;
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }
```

You need handle the click in the viewHolder class

```
class ViewHolderEntry extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
        {
            private TextView nameTextView;
            private TextView descriptionTextView;
            private TextView dueTextView;

            ViewHolderEntry(View itemView)
            {
                super(itemView);

                this.nameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameView);
                this.descriptionTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionView);
                this.dueTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dueView);
                itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            }


            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                clickListener.OnItemClicked(itemView,getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
```

You can create a method to get the specific **Entry** when you make the click.

Add a new method in your Adapter:

```
public Entry getItemAt(int position){
        return entries.get(position);
    }
```

And finally in your Activity you need implement the interface and handle the click:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements EntryAdapter.OnAdapterClick {

    EntryAdapter entryAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        entryAdapter = new EntryAdapter(list, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(entryAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void OnItemClicked(View v, int position) {
       Entry itemClicked = entryAdapter.getItemViewType(position);
       int id = itemClicked.getId();
    }
}
```

I think this help you.

Comment: Thank you so much, I started to implement your code and it seems promising ! But I have another problem now.. I should have mentionned it but I have 2 RecyclerView, pretty much doing the same thing (there can be 2 types of entries). So, in the MainActivity, how can I bind the two OnClick to the two RecyclerViews ? Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Because in the adapter view holder you are passing the View, then in the main activity you can get the id of that view and know which view was clicked

Comment: But if you are using a different adapter? I mean if you have 2 differents types of Entries is that a differente model?4

Comment: No, it's just the "type" (int) that differs, the model is the same. The thing is I use 2 same Adapters : one for the first type of Entry and the other for the second type... I don't know if it's the right way to do it, but since I got two different RecyclerView I guess yes ?

Comment: This recyclerview are in different activities? If is the case you just need implement the interface on the another activity and that all

Comment: Do you have the source code in Github? I could take a look if you want.

Comment: I don't have it on GitHub, but I managed to get it working ! Thank you so much for your help, I'm marking you as the answer :)

Comment: Thanks! Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Post your Entry model and MainActivity class. I believe you have already defined RecyclerView in another XML file.
PS: I'll edit this answer after you provide these two files.

Answer (score 0):

In your **ViewHolderEntry** *Construtor* add this line after decalring the image in the class and then set the clickListener for the image

```
buttonValidate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonValidate)
buttonValidate.setOnClickListener(this)
```

For this you must implement the interface View.OnClickListener then apply this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int position = getLayoutPosition(); // this gives the position of item in the recycler view
    Entry entry = (Entry) v.getTag();
    // now you can fetch all the information about the entry as for ex. for id 
    //int id = entry.getId();
}
```

So, finally your code will look like this

```
class ViewHolderEntry extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private TextView nameTextView;
    private TextView descriptionTextView;
    private TextView dueTextView;
    //add this line
    private ImageView buttonValidate;

    ViewHolderEntry(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);

        this.nameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameView);
        this.descriptionTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionView);
        this.dueTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dueView);
        // add this lines
        this.buttonValidate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonValidate);
        buttonValidate.setOnClickListener(this)
    }
// overrid this method
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = getLayoutPosition(); // this gives the position of item in the recycler view
        Entry entry = (Entry) v.getTag();
        // now you can fetch all the information about the entry as for ex. for id 
        //int id = entry.getId();
    }
}
```